# How do I format the time portion of my ".start" to write to my outlook appointment? I want to use input from the user of the form here is my

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

How do I format the time portion of my `.start` to write to my Outlook Appointment?

I want to use input from the user of the form here is my code.

This code creates an appointment on my calendar but sets the time to `12:00AM` instead of grabbing the input time (Scheduled_Review_Time) from the form.

I have tried Long, Medium, and Short time format in properties.

```
private Sub Command160_Click()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olApt As AppointmentItem


Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olApt = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)


With olApt
.Start = Me.Scheduled_Review_Date
.End = Me.Scheduled_Review_Date
.Subject = Me.Title_of_Product
.Location = Me.Review_Location
.Body = "Please Join us for A Meeting"
.Duration = Me.Duration
' .To = Me.
   .BusyStatus = olBusy
   .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15
   .ReminderSet = True


    .Save
End With


Set olApt = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: To clarify, your form has both a Scheduled_Review_Date and Scheduled_Review_Time because your code only takes into consideration the date.  Are you asking how to combine the date and time fields on your form?

Comment: Yes how do i combine them? I have tried ".Start = Me.Scheduled_Review_Date + me.Scheduled_Review_Time" and that was not correct .

Answer (score 0):

Your form is likely showing text values that look like dates and times. Convert to true date and time values with CDate and CTime.

```
With olApt

    .Start = cdate(Me.Scheduled_Review_Date) + cdate(me.Scheduled_Review_Time)
    'add 30 minutes for an end time
    .End = cdate(Me.Scheduled_Review_Date) + cdate(me.Scheduled_Review_Time) + timeserial(0, 30, 0)
    .Subject = Me.Title_of_Product
    .Location = Me.Review_Location
    .Body = "Please Join us for A Meeting"
    .Duration = Me.Duration
    ' .To = Me.
       .BusyStatus = olBusy
       .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15
       .ReminderSet = True

    .Save
End With
```

Comment: `timeserial(0, 30, 0)` or `Duration = Me.Duration`

Comment: Ctime not defined function VBA

Comment: You're correct of course. They should both be CDate since CDate converts both date and time.

Answer (score 0):

Option Explicit

```
Private Sub Command160_Click()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olApt As AppointmentItem

Dim Scheduled_Review_Date As Date
Dim Scheduled_Review_Time As Date
Dim Scheduled_Start As Date
Dim Title_of_Product As String
Dim Review_Location As String
Dim actDuration As String

Scheduled_Review_Date = DateSerial(2019, 2, 1)
Scheduled_Review_Time = TimeSerial(11, 35, 0)
Scheduled_Start = Scheduled_Review_Date + Scheduled_Review_Time
Title_of_Product = "Title_of_Product"
Review_Location = "Review_Location"
actDuration = "90"

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olApt = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

With olApt
.Start = Scheduled_Start
'.End = Me.Scheduled_Review_Date
.Subject = Title_of_Product
.Location = Review_Location
.Body = "Please Join us for A Meeting"
.Duration = actDuration
' .To = Me.
   .BusyStatus = olBusy
   .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15
   .ReminderSet = True


    .Save
End With

olApt.Display
Stop

Set olApt = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub
```